# How to avoid huge test refactoring on form change in Django

Tags: python, django, testing

Suppose there is a model, like:

```
class Book(Model):
    title = CharField(...)
```

So now I decide to add a choice field. So I add one plus set the default value thinking that this will allow me not to refactor code that much:

```
class Book(Model):
    title = CharField(...)
    book_type = ChoiceField(..., default=SOME_CHOICE_DEFAULT)
```

But unfortunately this forces to me to refactor a lot of tests. For example there about 10 tests for the form for this model like:

```
def test_book_form_is_invalid_on_some_condition():
    form = BookForm({'title': 'iwfew23@f'})
    assert not form.is_valid()
```

I have to add a `book_type` field to each one. This is really frustrating.
Also I have to refactor more functional tests:

```
def test_update_view_changes_something(admin_client):
    admin_client.post(reverse('book:update'), {'title': 'some_title'})
    ...
```

This will also complain that `book_type` isn't there.

How do I deal with such cascade refactoring when introducing a small model change?

I guess one of the ways to challenge this would be to introduce a global fixture which contains a default form data:

```
 @pytest.fixture
 def book_form_data():
     return {'title': 'some title'}

 def test_some_form_test(book_form_data):
     book_form_data['title'] = 'another title for this test'
     form = BookForm(book_form_data)
     ...
```

So the only place where I should add `book_type` will be this fixture. But that does not look quite right as well.

Comment: Hmm, I know it's tough for the refactoring, but tests are meant to test the validation of the functionality. Since your form has changes in the functionality, your test should be reflecting that as well. Isn't it? Your suggestion makes sense, why not stick to that?

Comment: @ShangWang in my case the change is transparent for all the code except for the tests. Maybe it's good that tests fail after such a change but I want to minimize that boilerplate work. Otherwise it forces me to make less changes as any change produces a lot of work. I do not like my concrete solution because if I need to remove some fields from it I should call `del book_form_data['title']`,  I can easily forget that there is a `title` field in it so when I do `admin_client.post(..., data=book_form_data)` I can spend quite a time figuring out where the `title` comes from in a view.

Comment: if you add a required field to something there's no way around changing the tests... except to try and make it more DRY by centralising the sensitive code parts, eg the fixture looks a good idea to me.  you could also look into using https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ it's not just for model instances

Comment: @Anentropic factoryboy could be a cool tool but I do not see how to combine it with Forms, because they expect a dictionary and there is no easy way of representing factory object data as a dict. At least I do not see how.

Comment: I think you're probably better off with pytest fixtures, but factoryboy is an object factory framework and dicts are objects

Comment: This is part of the ongoing debate surrounding proper test writing methodology. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGtasFJnUxI